# Update timestamp only when a non-NULL value is entered in another field

Tags: mysql, triggers, timestamp

Say there's a table with the following fields:

```
ID (auto-increment, int, primary)
NAME (varchar 60)
LOC_LAT (float 8,6)
LOC_LONG (float 9,6)
LASTSEEN (timestamp)
```

I really like the *timestamp* data type since it take the timezone recalculation bit off my shoulders by storing everything as UTC. However, it updates every time anything is changed anywhere in the table. What I need is for the **LASTSEEN** field to update with a new timestamp ONLY when either of **LOC_LAT** or **LOC_LONG** fields is updated with a non-NULL value. Is it possible? Or must I resort to datetime?

Here's what I tried but it doesn't do anything at all:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger_last_seen`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trigger_last_seen`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `distilled` FOR EACH ROW IF (NEW.LOC_LAT != NULL OR NEW.LOC_LONG != NULL)
THEN SET NEW.LASTSEEN = current_timestamp();
END IF
```

The above trigger does nothing – not even an error!

Answer (score 1):

Use `IS NOT NULL` rather than `!=`

Comment: Tried IS NOT NULL but it throws this error: `MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL OR NEW.LONGITUDE IS NOT NULL NULL) THEN UPDATE `distilled_contacts` SET NE' at line 1`

Comment: You have null twice in there which is a problem.  Also you may need to add parentheses around each of the is not null statements, but I don't think that would be the case

Comment: Here's what I tried: IF ((NEW.LATITUDE IS NOT NULL NULL) OR (NEW.LONGITUDE IS NOT NULL NULL))
THEN UPDATE `distilled_contacts` SET NEW.LASTSEEN = now();
END IF

Comment: right, you have null twice in each of those, that is the syntax error, you don't do `is not null null`, just do `is not null`

Comment: Oops! That's a shame. Corrected it and the trigger throws no error anymore. However, when I tried to update a record in the table in question, this is what it gives: #1442 - Can't update table 'distilled_contacts' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: It may not work to update a table within a trigger that uses an invariant for that same table, that's what I interpret from that message

Comment: Yes there does exist another trigger on a different table that updates/inserts a record in this table when there's an insert/update on the other one. Does that mean I can't use a trigger based on a row that's itself a result of another trigger? How does one get around this limitation then??

Comment: ah yes, it looks like it might be a nesting issue